# Firebase Auth with Multiple Providers

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to link the email/password, google and Facebook sign in?

I have successfully linked Google and Facebook sign in without any issue, however whenever I try to link Facebook with email/password & Google, I do get an error which is

```
account-exists-with-different-credential
```

OR

can I just prevent using the same email(gmail.com) when using Google Sign in when the user already registered using email and password method.

**Note:
I am using the same email for the three providers..**

There are no codes currently, since I do wanna ask first if this is the intended function of it.

I already tried using `try` `catch` for Google Sign in whenever the user signs in with a registered email via `email` and password, however it does not catch using `FirebaseAuthException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the official documentation, following the link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/errors#handling_account-exists-with-different-credential_errors